# How do you compare two arrays to get the count of similar objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, compare

I have two string arrays with unique amounts of content and data in each.

I want to be able to find the *count* of the number of items that appear in both arrays.

Example:

```
var array1 = ["Duck", "Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Elephant", "Cow", "Goat", "Goose"]
var array2 = ["Eagle", "Giraffe", "Cow", "Elephant", "Sheep", "Penguin", "Rhinoceros"]
```

This should print 2, because Cow and Elephant appear in both array1 and array2.

My progress is below. This is throwing an error: *Closure tuple parameter '(offset: Int, element: (String, String))' does not support destructuring with implicit parameters*

```
let compared = zip(array1, array2).enumerated().filter() {
    $1.0.id == $1.1.id
}.count

print(compared)
```

**How do I find the count of items that appear in both arrays?** *Note, there will never be 3 or more arrays. Always will compare 2 arrays.*

Comment: would they be always the same length too and the elements in each array would not be repeated??

Comment: No. The only consistent factor here is there will always be 2 arrays. Content, and length will differ. EDIT: Order will not be consistent either.

Comment: repeated elements within the same array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Set` operation:

```
var array1 = ["Duck", "Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Elephant", "Cow", "Goat", "Goose"]
var array2 = ["Eagle", "Giraffe", "Cow", "Elephant", "Sheep", "Penguin", "Rhinoceros"]

print( Set(array1).intersection(array2).count ) //-> 2
```

Comment: That was incredibly quick! Works like a charm!! Thank you @OOPer

Comment: @Joe, please remember, if you want to use other equality check than `==` (for example case-insesitive compare), using `Set` would be a little more difficult thing.

Comment: thank you for the heads up. For this comparison, it will always be case-sensitive, so your solution should work just fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a generic function that returns the common elements of two arrays by returning the intersection of the two `Set`s created from the `Array`s. The `Hashable` generic type restriction is needed since elements of a `Set` need to conform to `Hashable`.

```
func commonElements<T:Hashable>(between array1:[T],and array2:[T])->[T]{
    return Array(Set(array1).intersection(Set(array2)))
}

commonElements(between: array1, and: array2) // ["Cow", "Elephant"]
```

If you are only interested in the number of such elements, you can simply call `count` on the return value.

```
commonElements(between: array1, and: array2).count // 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your more detailed explanation @Dávid, . That information is helpful!